# Can I use the names or logos of real football teams in my game?

Tags: legal, copyright, trademark

I am developing a football game and I want to know if it is legal to name teams after real football teams. What about their logos?

Comment: This is a legal question, and if you're worried, you should ask a lawyer. That said (and Not-A-Lawyer), a good rule of thumb for content is: if you don't have explicit permission in some form, don't use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names of sports teams names are usually trademarks of their owning corporation or entity, as are the logos. You cannot use them as teams in your games without permission.

This is a legal matter; you should contact your lawyer for definitive advice.